# gausspr function from R package kernlab hangs on linear kernel

Tags: r, kernlab

I am experimenting with gaussian process model and in particular the implementation in the kernlab R package. I found the model fitting hangs when excised with linear kernels. Profiling shows it is busy doing matrix multiplication via operator "%*%". A reproducible example is given below:

```
data(iris)
#this doesn't hang
test <- kernlab::gausspr(Species~.,data=iris,type="classification",kernel="rbfdot")
#this hangs with message "Setting default kernel parameters"
test <- kernlab::gausspr(Species~.,data=iris,type="classification",kernel="vanilladot")
#this also hangs
test <- kernlab::gausspr(Species~.,data=iris,type="classification",kernel="polydot", kpar=list(degree=1))
#this doesn't hang
test <- kernlab::gausspr(Species~.,data=iris,type="classification",kernel="polydot", kpar=list(degree=2))
```

Any idea what is going on here? Many thanks!

Comment: update: the problem is traced down to the `while` loop solving for `alphag`, where the `gradnorm` oscillates between 0.01 and 0.02 after 6 loops, not vanishing to zero...

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify different tuning hyperparameters `kpar` for each kernel type. The **default** option is **kpar = list(sigma = 0.1)**, which works only for the **Gaussian** kernel.

The list of hyperparameters for each kernel `kpar` is below:

- `sigma` inverse kernel width for the Radial Basis kernel function "**rbfdot**" and the Laplacian kernel "**laplacedot**".
- `degree, scale, offset` for the Polynomial kernel "**polydot**".
- `scale, offset` for the Hyperbolic tangent kernel function "**tanhdot**".
- `sigma, order, degree` for the Bessel kernel "**besseldot**".
- `sigma, degree` for the ANOVA kernel "**anovadot**".

If you want to understand better why, check the kernel functions in [this pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kernlab/kernlab.pdf), on page 9.

However things are a bit trickier for the simple LINEAR kernel, i.e. **kernel = vanilladot**. There are NO hyperparameters to be specified. I tried kpar = NA, but it did not work. I figured out a way to get the LINEAR kernel results using the polynomial one with special tuning:

```
test <- kernlab::gausspr(Species~.,data=iris,type="classification",
                     kernel="polydot", kpar=list(degree =1, scale =1, offset =0))
```